# Matlab detect darker red in all red image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to analyze medical image by segmenting darker red from this image, because the darker red indicating internal bleeding. (Sorry if the image looks creepy).
[image]

```
1st image is original image

2nd image with adjusted contrast

3rd grayscale image

4th binary image with not setting threshold

5th binary image with minthreshold 0 and maxthreshold 15

6th imcomplement image
```

The problem here is, if you see the original image, you can see darker red on the upper right,  and thin dark red line on the swollen part in the middle, which is the internal bleeding I want to get...but I cant get it.

Is there any specific method to get it?

Any help I really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try segmentation in LAB color space:

```
colorTransform = makecform('srgb2lab');
I = applycform(I, colorTransform);
imshow(I(:,:,2)>165)
```

[image]

I implement the lab conversion on your original image, you can try to observe the difference on your image with intensity adjusted.

Comment: Thanks lennon, it works! You saved me! I'm still lacking of knowledge in image processing and matlab hehe

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SegmentTool: An Interactive GUI for Segmenting Images](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38484-segmenttool-an-interactive-gui-for-segmenting-images)

Comment: Thanks @Dima. I'll try it. i just found that suggested method above not applicable on different image where I want to detect a smaller area of dark red.